# Date comparison in xsl

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I have two dates in format YYYYMMDD in variables.

```
<xsl:variable name ="date1" select =" 20140401" />
<xsl:variable name ="date2" select =" 20140801" />
```

How to compare and get the most recent date in xsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that format you can do number comparison `$date1 lt; $date2`, even with XSLT 1.0. With XSLT 2.0 you would construct `xs:date` values and compute the `max` value.